# Working with jsoncpp to automate outputing json data

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am trying to automate the process of outputing the broad disciplines of UC Berkeley's majors. I have shortened the code and the JSON data to make the issue clearer. It is stored in JSON format and I am using the jsoncpp api to work with the data. The json data is the following:

```
{ "Berkeley": {
"1" :
{
"Broad Discipline": "Agriculture & Natural Resources",
"College/School**": "Letters & Science",
"Major": "ENVIRONMENTAL ECONOMICS & POLICY",
"Admit GPA Range": "3.63 - 3.94",
"Admit Rate": "0.342105263",
"Enroll GPA Range": "3.65 - 3.94",
"Yield Rate": "0.730769231",
"Admits": "26",
"Apps": "76",
"Enrolls": "19"
},
"2" :
{
"Broad Discipline": "Agriculture & Natural Resources",
"College/School**": "Natural Resources",
"Major": "CONSERVATION & RESOURCE STUDIES",
"Admit GPA Range": "3.32 - 3.88",
"Admit Rate": "0.333333333",
"Enroll GPA Range": "3.30 - 3.90",
"Yield Rate": "0.818181818",
"Admits": "22",
"Apps": "66",
"Enrolls": "18"
}
}}
```

Prior to this section of code, root is a json::Value and holds all the json data shown above.

```
// for loop through school's broad disciplines
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  string element = "\"" + to_string(i + 1) + "\"";
  string broadDiscipline = (root["Berkeley"][element]["Broad Discipline"]).asString();
  cout << "Broad Discipline: " << broadDiscipline << endl;
}
```

I would expect it to output:

```
Broad Discipline: "Agriculture & Natural Resources"
Broad Discipline: "Agriculture & Natural Resources"
```

The actual result is:

```
Broad Discipline: 
Broad Discipline:
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Also I can not find the documentation in jsoncpp for whatever function is called in a command like: root["Berkeley"].

Comment: Why are you putting quotes around the number but not the key strings?

Comment: Sorry, but what are you referring to as the key string?

Comment: `"Broad Discipline"` is syntax used to represent the string `Broad Discipline` (no quotes in the real string). That's what you're using for string keys (and prob correct). But for the numeric key, you're adding double quotes. (Equivalent to the string literal `"\"1\""`.)

Comment: I took out the quotes, but the error check I do earlier in the code using jsoncpp's function getFormattedErrorMessages() outputs the following error when I take out those double quotes: *Line 2, Column 3 Missing '}' or object member name

Comment: Instead of representing your data with {"1": {...}, "2": {...}} you should represent it as list [ {...}, {...}] If it's not possible, please use some standard int to string conversion.